# Is there an open subspace of a locally compact space that is not locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The definition used here is:

> A space $X$ is locally compact, if $\forall x\in X$, there exists a compact neighborhood.

I want to find an example that **an open subspace of a locally compact space is not locally compact**. I examined the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{Q}$, but didn't find such examples.

Did I miss something? Or no such examples?

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{Q}$ open in the one-point compactification?

Comment: @ZhenLin It is, but $\mathbb Q$ is not locally compact so also the one-point compactification of $\mathbb Q$ is not locally compact.

Comment: Under any reasonable definition of locally compact space, sure. But the OP has chosen the naïve definition where every compact space is locally compact.

Comment: @ZhenLin Sorry, that's true. You can always take the whole space as compact neighborhood. So $\mathbb Q$ answers the question!

Comment: @ZhenLin You're right. I should have noticed the fact.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

$\mathbb{Q}$ is open in its one-point compactification, it is not locally compact, and the one-point compactification is locally compact under your definition.